# The proper way of defining map loaders from application - hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

I have an application using Hazelcast in the embedded mode. I use MapLoaders and indexes. I want to change my application so I can use an existing external Hazelcast cluster to which I will connect using the client api and here lies my problem. There is no way of defining those map loaders in the client app, so I need to use the server mode. Right now I'm using the JoinConfig so I can join the cluster and define my map loaders, but if I understand correctly, by joining the cluster my app will become a part of the cluster itself (and host some data partitions) and this is something I would like to avoid. So is there another way of connecting to this external cluster so my app doesn't start hosting the cache data, or is my approach correct and I shouldn't mind being a part of the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Hazelcast Client, it just connects to the cluster, but it does not become part of the cluster. It seems like what you want.

Concerning Map Loaders, please check the [related code sample](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/learning-basics/configure-datastructures-at-runtime).

Comment: I know to define and write map loaders, what I don't know is if there is a way of configuring maps on the cluster without joining it and hosting its data or in more general, what is a general pattern of doing such a thing (configuring maps).

Comment: If you don't want to connect to the cluster (use Hazelcast Client), then there would need to be some other Hazelcast API (like a REST) to reconfigure the cluster. But AFAIK there is nothing like that.

Comment: I can't connect with Hazelcast Client for the purpose of configuring the maps, as Client api doesn't support this. Only server side api supports this and the only way I found is to use the JoinConfig and so become part of the cluster itself. My question is if I understand this join mechanic correctly (do I indeed start hosting the cluster data?) and if so, is there a way to connect to server, use server api but do not start hosting the cluster data.